# Can I move my current tab to a split in a different tab?

Tags: vim-windows, split, tabbed-user-interface

This happens to me semi-frequently. I have two tabs open, and I would like to merge them into one tab with a vertical split. Essentially, I want to do the opposite of [CTRL-w_T](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#CTRL-W_T). Right now, I have to this:

```
:wq<cr><C-w>v:browse old<cr>q1<cr>
```

Is there any more convenient way to do this? If there isn't a builtin way, I wouldn't be opposed to adding a vimscript function, or installing a plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move existing window to existing tab](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/move-existing-window-to-existing-tab)

Comment: @EvergreenTree No, that is the *inverse* of what I want to do.

Comment: It's really not... Open window in a split of an existing tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, try the following:

```
function! MergeTab()
    let bufnums = tabpagebuflist()
    hide tabclose
    topleft vsplit
    for n in bufnums
        execute 'sbuffer ' . n
        wincmd _
    endfor
    wincmd t
    quit
    wincmd =
endfunction
command! MergeTab call MergeTab()
```

It will merge all windows in a tab into a vertical
split at the left hand side of the following tab (or the preceding tab
if you happen to be on the last tab).

There might be issues if you run out of room, but you'll
still have your buffers in the buffer list.

Comment: You could let it take optional arguments. Then if there *was* an argument go to that tab, otherwise use this behavior. Just an idea for robustness.

Comment: Yeah, that might be nice if that situation arises a lot. Otherwise you could just do a `:tabmove` first.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty solution (only works if you have exactly two tabs):

```
vim -p file1 file2

:exe 'normal! gt' | exe 'vsplit ' . bufname('#') | exe "normal! gt"| q
```

Explanation:

- Move to the other tab to make the first tab the alternate file,
- `vsplit` against the alternate file,
- Move to the other tab again and quit.

---

A little better solution, it works when you have more tabs but leaves a global variable hanging:

```
:let this_tab = bufname('%') | exe 'normal! gt' | exe 'vsplit ' . this_tab | exe "normal! gT"| q | unlet this_tab
```

Explanation (same as above but):

- Saves the buffer on the tab on the left,
- Uses the saved buffer when performing `vsplit`.

(the hanging variable can be avoided by making a function)

Comment: This very much worked for me, thanks a ton!